# LINQ select multiple items based on comparison

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to get some values from LINQ query but i am not being able to code the rite syntax here is the Model

```
public class ViewHistorySheetModel {
    public string SheetName { get; set; }
    public List<ViewHistoryDataModel> lData { get; set; }
    public List<CountHistoryDataModel> RData { get; set; }
}

public class CountHistoryDataModel
{
    public string RId { get; set; }
    public string RIndex { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the code i am trying 
I want to get `RIndex` against matching `RId`

```
int Revision=1234;
var indexs = (select r.RIndex from Model.RData where r.RId= Revision);
foreach(var index in indexs)
{
// functionalty
}
```

Comment: just ordering and your assignment/equality operator is wrong. You want `from r in Model.RData where r.RId == Revision select r.RIndex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this, your ordering of lines is not right and few syntax errors as well:

```
var indexs = (from r in Model.RData 
              where r.RId == Revision
              select r.RIndex);
```

and iterate now:

```
foreach(var index in indexs)
{
// do something
}
```

you can also use lambda expression like this:

```
var indexs = Model.RData.Where(r=>r.RId == Revision).Select(r => r.Index);
```

you can see more details [Here for Lambda Expressions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/298963/Understand-Lambda-Expressions-in-minutes)

**UPDATED:**

Though my answer accepted as it helped out the OP but OP did a little modification to get the desired results. Here that is:

```
var indexs = (from r in Model.SelectMany(c => c.RData) 
              where r.RId == revision.RevisionID 
              select r.RIndex);
```

Comment: it says Model is property but used like a type

Comment: i will recomment to go with lambda expression as its clean and one liner

Comment: (from r in Model.SelectMany(c => c.RData) where r.RId == revision.RevisionID select r.RIndex);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52810/discussion-between-adil-waqar-and-ehsan-sajjad)